# Convert string with separator to data class instance

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string separated by ";" like this:

```
var dataString: String = "Juan;25;Argentina"
```

And I want to convert it to this sample data class:

```
data class Person (
var name: String? = "",
var age: Int? = "",
var location: String? = "")
```

The only way I figured out to that is like this:

```
var dataString: String = "Juan;25;Argentina"
var fieldList = dataString.split(";").map { it.trim() }
var personItem = Person(fieldList[0], fieldList[1], fieldList[2])
```

But this is too static, if I then have to add new field to Person data class, I have to manually add fieldList[3]

Which is the most efficient way to do this? (I searched a lot, but couldn't find it :S )

**SOLUTION:**

```
//Data in string
val rawData = "name;age;location\nPerson1;20;USA\nPerson2;30;Germany" 

//Custom string reader with ";" separator
val customCSV = csvReader { delimiter = ';' }

//String to map list
val parsed = csvReader().readAllWithHeader(rawData)

//Mal list to list of <Person>
val finalData = grass<Person>().harvest(parsed)
for (entry in entryList) {
   //entry is an instance of Person
}
```

EDIT2:
You can obtain field names for header line like this:

```
var headerLine = ""
for (entry in Person::class.members) {
   if (member.name.isNotEmpty())
       headerLine += ";${member.name}"
}
headerLine.substring(1)
```

Comment: JSON format is the better way to use for this type of information.

Comment: Thanks, but Im provided with a CSV file from an external system

Comment: I don't think there's really a good way to do this, outside of using a library that just generates code and automates the mapping to parameters for you. The language enforces defining your constructors, and checking that one of the constructors is called with the correct number and type of parameters. You could *possibly* do something with reflection, but now you're going around the language and its safety features and making it more brittle and harder to maintain. If you want a formally defined data class, and you change its structure, why can't you update the calls? Refactoring helps too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you showed here looks like a CSV dataset. So I think you could use kotlin-grass and kotlin-csv

https://github.com/blackmo18/kotlin-grass
https://github.com/doyaaaaaken/kotlin-csv/

Example:

```
val rawData = "Person1;20;USA/nPerson1;30;Germany"

val parsed = csvReader().readAllWithHeader(rawData)
val finalData = grass<Person>().harvest(parsed)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!! But some changes to what you wrote: 1) A header line is mandatory in rawData 2) I had to create a custom csvReader as it uses "," as default separator, so: val customCSV = csvReader {  delimiter = ';'  }

Comment: Oh okay I' m sorry I wrote the answer on my mobile. Happy to hear that it works :)